# FloatingPane close and reopen

Tags: javascript, dojo

PROBLEM

I have a dojo floatingPane with a calendar attached. When I start up my floatingpane everything is ok. But when I close it and reopen it it glitches somehow and only displays the frane of the pane without and I don't know what exactly is wrong or where it goes wrong at all.

THE CODE

http://pastebin.com/bu8SripW

HOW IT LOOKS LIKE

[image: First open]
[image: After closing and reopening]

I tried practically everything I could think of so far but I just can't make it work. I know I'm halfway there but I'm running low on ideas at the moment.

Comment: I'd connect the resize or show events of the floating pane and try resizing the inside content at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was connected to the fact I didn't kill of the calendar on window close event.